# Como customizar as mensagens do select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Quero retirar as mensagens do Select2:

1. Searching;
2. No matches found;

Segue o código abaixo:

Pagina Html

```html
<input id="ajaxSecretaria" type="hidden" style="width:300px" />
```

Script:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#ajaxSecretaria').select2(
    { minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
      ajax: {
        url: '@Url.Action("GetSecretarias", "Home")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return { searchTerm: term };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
                 return {results: data};
        }
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: Você quer realmente customizar ou apenas traduzir?

Comment: Quero que não apareça a mensagem.

Answer (score 0):

É bem simples customizar basta colocar as instruções abaixo na chamada de seu  JavaScript assim:

```
formatNoMatches: function () { return "Pesquisa não encontrada"; },
formatInputTooShort: function (input, min) { return "Digite " + (min - input.length) + " caracteres para pesquisar"; },
formatSelectionTooBig: function (limit) { return "Selecione apenas 1 opção " + limit + " item" + (limit == 1 ? "" : "s"); },
formatLoadMore: function (pageNumber) { return "Carregando mais dados..."; },
formatSearching: function () { return "Pesquisando..."; }
```

Answer (score 0):

O titulo da pergunta fala em "Customizar", mas no comentário fala em não aparecer a mensagem, então dito isso, os códigos abaixo ajudam na parte de esconder e não customizar.

Para remover o Search vc pode usar o seguinte código:

```
$('select').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1
});
```

Já para remover o No matches found vc pode usar css:

```
.select2-no-results {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Um exemplo usado em um modal

$('#card').select2({
dropdownParent: $("#modal-open-order"),
placeholder: 'Clique para abrir uma Ficha',
language: {
noResults: function() {
return "Nenhum resultado encontrado";
}
}
});
O código que você forneceu está usando o plugin Select2 jQuery para aprimorar um elemento com recursos adicionais, como pesquisa e menus suspensos personalizados.

1 - $('#card').select2({ ... });: Este código inicializa o plugin Select2 no elemento com o ID card. Ele aprimora o elemento selecionado com várias opções e configurações.

2 - dropdownParent: $("#modal-open-order"): Esta opção especifica que o menu suspenso do elemento selecionado deve ser anexado ao elemento com o ID modal-open-order. Ou seja, ao abrir o dropdown, ele aparecerá dentro do modal com o ID modal-open-order.

3 - placeholder: 'Clique para abrir uma Ficha': esta opção define o texto do espaço reservado para o elemento selecionado. Ele fornece um texto padrão para exibir quando nenhuma opção for selecionada.

4 - language: { noResults: function() { return "Nenhum resultado encontrado"; } }: Esta parte personaliza as configurações de idioma para Select2. Ele define o texto a ser exibido quando nenhum resultado for encontrado. Neste caso, se nenhum resultado correspondente for encontrado durante uma pesquisa, será exibido "Nenhum resultado encontrado", que significa "Nenhum resultado encontrado" em português.

No geral, esse código inicializa um elemento de seleção aprimorado Select2, personaliza o texto do espaço reservado e especifica uma mensagem personalizada para quando nenhum resultado for encontrado durante uma pesquisa. Também garante que o menu suspenso seja exibido dentro de um elemento modal específico com o ID modal-open-order.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).